# I created a class that builds a deck of cards but the string representation of the Deck is returned. How do I get it to be represented as a string

Tags: python

I created two classes, one for the Card which can print any of the 52 cards and another class to build the Deck, I iterated through the range card class to build the whole deck I tried print(), return, str() but it keeps returning the object of the string.

```
from random import shuffle 

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = ['Spade', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs'][suit]
        self.value = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King'][value]
    
    def reveal(self):
        print('Card is ' + self.value + ' of ' + self.suit)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.card = []
        for s in range(4):
            for v in range(13):
                self.card.append(Card(s,v))
        shuffle(self.card)
    
    def reveal(self):
        return self.card
    
    def draw(self):
        if self.card == []:
            return 'No more cards'
        else:
            return self.card.pop()
```

Comment: Which `print()` statement are you refering to?

Comment: Read about [`str` and `repr`](https://pythongeeks.org/python-repr-with-examples/)